# Generate matrix with iid normal random variables using R

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

Is there a way to generate a data set with normally distributed random values in R without using a loop? Each entry would represent an independent random variable with a normal distribution.

Comment: `matrix(rnorm(n*p),n)` for an $n \times p$ matrix with iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$ entries.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To create an `N` by `M` matrix of iid normal random variables type this:

```
matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M)
```

tweak the mean and standard deviation as desired.

Comment: As long as the questioner understands that N is the number of rows and M the number of columns, then he will be well served by this answer

Comment: @DWin, agreed. That is the conventional notation when referring to matrices in any context though, right?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I do know that people sometimes express surprise at the fact that R's matrices are filled in column-major order with calls to `matrix` unless byrow=TRUE. Ihat made me think that there might be variation in matrix conventions across various languages.

Comment: for `matrix` you can specify one of `nrow` or `ncol`

Answer (score 2):

let `mu` be a vector of means and `sigma` a vector of standard devs

```
mu<-1:10
sigma<-10:1
sample.size<-100
norm.mat<-mapply(function(x,y){rnorm(x,y,n=sample.size)},x=mu,y=sigma)
```

would produce a matrix with columns holding the relevant samples

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
replicate(NumbOfColumns,rnorm(NumbOfLines))
```

You can replace `rnorm` with other distribution function, for example `runif`, to generate matrices with other distributions.

Answer (score -3):

Notice: each entry is independent. So you cannot avoid using for loops, because you have to call rnorm once for each independent variable. If you just call rnorm(n*m) that's the n*m samples from the same random variable!

Comment: this is wrong, and confusing ...  `rnorm(n*m)` *does* generate `n*m` **independent** random samples, exactly as the OP requested.