# how to speed up a for loop with one core in R

Tags: r

How to speed up the following code inside a foreach %dopar%?

it is already embedded inside a paralleled foreach loop. Therefore, it better uses only one core.
But Is there any way to reduce its computational time a little bit with single core?
Thank you.

```
n = 1e5
k = 10

mu = 0
sigma = 1
x = matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=k)

for(j in 1:k) {
    for(i in 1:n) {
        x[i,j] = rnorm(1, mu, sigma)
    }
}
```

Comment: `x = matrix( rnorm(n*k,mean=mu,sd=sigma), n, k)` would be the vectorized approach, should be much faster, about 35x faster at this scale and bigger difference as you expand loops.  Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640415/generate-matrix-with-iid-normal-random-variables-using-r.   Why to use vectorization: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f1 = function(){
n = 1000
k = 1000
  
mu = 0
sigma = 1
x = matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=k)
  
for(j in 1:k) {
   for(i in 1:n) {
    x[i,j] = rnorm(1, mu, sigma)
  }
 }
}


f2 = function(){
  n = 1000
  k = 1000
  
  mu = 0
  sigma = 1
  
  data = rnorm(n*k, mu, sigma)
  x = matrix(data=data, nrow=n, ncol=k)
}
system.time(f1())
system.time(f2())
```

`f2()` is almost 32 times faster

Comment: Upvoted.  Good answer.  I figured out the vector to matrix trick a while ago myself.  Whenever anybody has an urge to use a for loop in R, they should mediate on vectorization for few moments until it goes away.